# Elasticsearch - query mach and rang

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have one index with a lot of information and I can't find the correct query to get the data.

example of the index:

```
    "_index" : "us_employees",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_source" : {
      "id": "12345678",
      "name": "employee1",
      "group": "IT",
      "dateOfstart": "2022-01-01"

    "_index" : "us_employees",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_source" : {
      "id": "87654321",
      "name": "employee2",
      "group": "IT",
      "dateOfstart": "2022-06-1"

    "_index" : "us_employees",
    "_type" : "doc",
    "_source" : {
      "id": "2382342",
      "name": "employee3",
      "group": "back_office",
      "dateOfstart": "2022-02-03"
```

I would like to get the query that finds all the employees in the same group ("IT" for example) and that they start after "2022-01-01"

so I tried:

```
GET us_employees/_search
{
"query": {
  "range": {
    "dateOfstart": {
       "gte": "2022-01-01 00:00:00.000",
       "lte": "2022-08-19 23:59:59.000"
  }
},
  "match_phrase": {
    "group": "IT"
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context) because you works with cache.

My suggestion:

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "group.keyword": "IT"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "dateOfstart": {
              "gte": "2020-01-01",
              "lte": "2022-08-19"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```